# Vue.js: Not Getting CSS Reference of External Component datetimepicker in the dist Folder

Tags: vue.js

I have used an external component datetimepicker in my component and it works fine as shown below when I run the project.

[image]

But while building for production as web component to get the min.js files inside dist directory, not getting CSS reference of that external component datetimepicker in the received js files inside the dist directory. It does not render styles of the datetimepicker field. It is displaying like below. Is there any solution for that?

[image]

I have executed below command:

```
$ npm install vuejs-datetimepicker
```

And used below code for that

```
<td align="left">                            
    <datetime format="DD-MM-YYYY h:i:s" width="280px" v-model="dateTime"></datetime>                    
</td>
```

```
import datetime from 'vuejs-datetimepicker';
export default {    
  components: {        
      datetime              
  }
}
```

And I used the command `npm run build` to build as web component.

[image]

[image]

Attaching my package file below:

```
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target wc-async --name common-apps 
./src/App.vue",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuejs-datetimepicker": "^1.1.13",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.2.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.2.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
"@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
"@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
"prettier": "^1.19.1",
"sass": "^1.25.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share some more details with us? How does your build pipeline look like? What exactly are you using? And please feel free to provide at least a minimal version of your dev and prod config.

Comment: is there any error or warning related is showing in console?

Comment: If prossible try importing css file related to that component inside your file.eg: -  
 import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css' // i used this pattern  for quill editor since it caused similary issue

Comment: It seems like your css file is not getting generated. Please share your config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue just by executing the command `npm install style-loader css-loader --save` in the terminal.

Comment: Hey facing exact the same issue with same package, but this isn't help me, you sure this did solved issue for you or is there anything else ?